# C# Select property with name

Tags: c#, reflection

*I am not sure how to word this question properly, so apologies at the very beginning.*

I am working with MongoDb and at some point, I need to design a lambda expression as follows:

```
...Set(g => g.Profile.First_Name, "Test");
```

Now, `g` refers to a class called `User`, which has a property of type `Profile`(a different class), with the same name `Profile`. As you can see, in the lambda expression, I am selecting the `First_Name` property and then passing the value `"Test"` to it.

My Question:
Is there a way to select the property by name?

In more detail - is something like this possible? :

```
 .... g.Profile. ("First_Name")
```

As I am typing this, even to me it sounds ridiculous, but I need to dynamically select the particular properties therefore I need to select them via their names.

How do I actually achieve this?

I tried :

```
g.Profile.GetType().GetProperty("First_Name")
```

But it doesn't seem to be equivalent to `g.Profile.First_Name`.

Any ideas on what can be done?

Comment: You need to provide a bit more information about what you're trying to do.
You mention MongoDb. Are you trying to update a document in MongoDb using MongoDb Driver?

Comment: Why is that not equivalent? Seems like you are on the right road to me... `GetProperty` will return a `PropertyInfo`, you then need to call `GetValue` or `SetValue` if you want to do something with it (passing the object to modify, `g.Profile` in this case). I'd put that as an answer but not sure where you are stuck

Comment: @Steve, yes. The document structure is of the structure of the `User` class, means that the document has fields same as the `User` class'es properties. Now, inside the `User` class, there's a `Profile` class, defined as a property as well. What i am trying to do is update only particular fields of the `Property` class, which is inside the `User` class. The issue here is that, i need to dynamically select ONLY the given properties. The property names would be served as string, so i need to find a way to select them based on the name provided.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, okay, how can i explain ? Okay, read my other comment and you'll get the idea here.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I think the issue is the fact that that `Set` takes a lambda of the property name and a value to set it to (which it then does in Mongo-speak).

Comment: @HereticMonkey, Not quite actually. Rather it works if i pass only a string instead of the lambda expression, like `.Set("First_Name" , "Test"). The problem here is that, in this way, MongoDb creates a new field called `First_Name` inside the `User` document, where as it had to create/set value for the field, which is in the `Profile` object, which is in the `User` object/document.

Comment: I think the answers to [LINQ select property by name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47781545/215552) might get you going in the right direction. Basically, you have to write the `Expression` manually rather than relying on the syntax. That can get tricky real quick; [Marc's answer is for a simple case where it's always a string property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47781545/215552). If you have a number of properties and they have different types, it can be daunting...

Comment: @RufusL, sorry, that won't work.

Comment: @Aousaf I figured there'd be an overload like that, with just that kind of limitation :(. I think my last comment might get you part way there; I'm still looking to see if there's a question where the property is nested like yours is. I think I've seen one, but apparently I didn't bookmark it.

Comment: Finally fixed it! Just did this : `.Set("Profile.First_Name", valueGoesHere)` and MongoDb worked as expected!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I probably don't *actually* want to use reflection here.

The `g => ...` is not actually a lambda function, but an [expression tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/index) — it's some fancy syntactic sugar for describing a process, in this case, a process for getting a certain property given a record of type `User`. MongoDB API provides overloads that allow expression so you can code 90% of your operations more gracefully, but if you really need to be dynamic you can of course bypass this, for example:

```
var setName = Builders<User>.Update.Set(g => g.Profile.First_Name, "Test");
```

Is roughly equivalent to something like:

```
var setName = Builders<User>.Update.Set("profile.first_name", "Test");
```

Of course, if you have `BsonProperty` attributes on your properties, custom conventions, etc. that can change the path of the BSON being updated.

Now, suppose you don't want to have to hard-code the BSON paths. Well, you can generate dynamic expression trees, but it's not very elegant or performant. You'd use something along the lines of this:

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User), "g");
Expression<Func<User, String>> expr =
    Expression.Lambda<Func<User, String>>(
        Expression.Property(
            Expression.Property(
                param,
                "Profile"
            ),
            "First_Name"
        ),
        new[] { param }
    );

 var setName = Builders<User>.Update.Set(expr, "Test");
```

Comment: `var setName = Builders<User>.Update.Set("profile.first_name", "Test");` i figured this part out and it works perfectly! Thanks