# LINQ Select columns base on array of string[]

Tags: c#, linq

I have a this method that would generate a query and would export it to excel.
I would like the users to choose which columns would they like to be exported on.

my question is kinda similar to this OP [LINQ select property by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47781469/linq-select-property-by-name)

Where we can create a **LINQ select query** in  base on list of `string[] columns` and which should be kinda similar to this `_dbcontext.Person.Select( SelectorFunc(columns) ).SomeOtherQuery().ToList();` 
query and function `SelectorFunc(columns)` below

```
public Func<Person, string[]> SelectorFunc(string[] columns) {
    //  ninja code!! 
   return " not sure here";
}
```

its kinda messy if i would have to do it manually like.

```
var query = _dbcontext.Person.AsQueryable();

if(column == "ID") 
  query = query.Select( x=x.ID);
if(column == "Name") 
  query = query.Select( x=x.Name);

//and the list goes on...
```

PS:
I really appreciate for the enlightenment and Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your case is Dynamic Select, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45205267/3789481 this answer is separate column fields by ",". So your string[] colums would be string.Join(",", colums ) to join it by comma

Comment: @TấnNguyên this is what exactly im looking for! thank you

Comment: I would suggest, generate dynamic SQL query[Select statements or Database Views ] on the basis of Selected Columns to Export and then use sql query via EF / ADO.NET, this will be very easy to handle and maintainable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a duplicate question from this OP [LINQ : Dynamic select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516971/linq-dynamic-select/45205267#45205267)

base on the those answer.

```
public static Func<T, T> SelectorFunc<T>(string[] columns)
{

        // input parameter "o"
        var xParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "o");

        // new statement "new Data()"
        var xNew = Expression.New(typeof(T));

        // create initializers
        var bindings = columns.Select(o => o.Trim())
            .Select(o =>
            {

                // property "Field1"
                var mi = typeof(T).GetProperty(o);

                // original value "o.Field1"
                var xOriginal = Expression.Property(xParameter, mi);

                // set value "Field1 = o.Field1"
                return Expression.Bind(mi, xOriginal);
            }
        );

        // initialization "new Data { Field1 = o.Field1, Field2 = o.Field2 }"
        var xInit = Expression.MemberInit(xNew, bindings);

        // expression "o => new Data { Field1 = o.Field1, Field2 = o.Field2 }"
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(xInit, xParameter);

        // compile to Func<Data, Data>
        return lambda.Compile();
}
```

and consuming the function would be `_dbcontext.Person.SomeOtherQuery().Select( SelectorFunc<Person>(columns) ).ToList()`

Thank you @Tấn Nguyên for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be help:
I found it from here 
[Dynamically select properties by string names](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3IMR1r)

this is your object:

```
    public class Foo
{
    public string Property1 {get;set;}
    public string Property2 {get;set;}  
}
```

this is your helper class:

```
  public static class ExpressionTreeHelper
{
    /// <summary> Returns an IEnumerable of anonymous type defined by <paramref name="properties"/>. </summary>
    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> SelectDynamic<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params string[] properties)
    {
        return SelectProperties<T>(source.AsQueryable(), properties).Cast<dynamic>();
    }

    private static IQueryable SelectProperties<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, IEnumerable<string> propertyNames)
    {
        // get propertyinfo's from original type
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => propertyNames.Contains(p.Name));

        // Create the x => expression
        var lambdaParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        // Create the x.<propertyName>'s
        var propertyExpressions = properties.Select(p => Expression.Property(lambdaParameterExpression, p));

        // Creating anonymous type using dictionary of property name and property type
        var anonymousType = AnonymousTypeUtils.CreateType(properties.ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.PropertyType));
        var anonymousTypeConstructor = anonymousType.GetConstructors().Single();
        var anonymousTypeMembers = anonymousType.GetProperties().Cast<MemberInfo>().ToArray();

        // Create the new {} expression using 
        var anonymousTypeNewExpression = Expression.New(anonymousTypeConstructor, propertyExpressions, anonymousTypeMembers);

        var selectLambdaMethod = GetExpressionLambdaMethod(lambdaParameterExpression.Type, anonymousType);
        var selectBodyLambdaParameters = new object[] { anonymousTypeNewExpression, new[] { lambdaParameterExpression } };
        var selectBodyLambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)selectLambdaMethod.Invoke(null, selectBodyLambdaParameters);

        var selectMethod = GetQueryableSelectMethod(typeof(T), anonymousType);
        var selectedQueryable = selectMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { queryable, selectBodyLambdaExpression }) as IQueryable;
        return selectedQueryable;
    }

    private static MethodInfo GetExpressionLambdaMethod(Type entityType, Type funcReturnType)
    { 
        var prototypeLambdaMethod = GetStaticMethod(() => Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(default(Expression), default(IEnumerable<ParameterExpression>))); 
        var lambdaGenericMethodDefinition = prototypeLambdaMethod.GetGenericMethodDefinition(); 
        var funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(entityType, funcReturnType); 
        var lambdaMethod = lambdaGenericMethodDefinition.MakeGenericMethod(funcType); 
        return lambdaMethod; 
    } 

    private static MethodInfo GetQueryableSelectMethod(Type entityType, Type returnType)
    { 
        var prototypeSelectMethod = GetStaticMethod(() => Queryable.Select(default(IQueryable<object>), default(Expression<Func<object, object>>))); 
        var selectGenericMethodDefinition = prototypeSelectMethod.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
        return selectGenericMethodDefinition.MakeGenericMethod(entityType, returnType);
    } 

    private static MethodInfo GetStaticMethod(Expression<Action> expression)
    { 
        var lambda = expression as LambdaExpression; 
        var methodCallExpression = lambda.Body as MethodCallExpression; 
        return methodCallExpression.Method; 
    } 
}
```

and call by this way:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var list = new[] {new Foo { Property1 = "foo1" }, new Foo { Property1 = "foo2" }};

    var result = list.SelectDynamic(nameof(property).toString());

    result.Dump();
}
```